# Flight itinerary/time/date change

Tags: cancellations, compensation, vueling

I have booked a flight from Tenerife South to Olbia via Barcelona recently with Vueling airlines.

The itinerary looked like this: 21.07.2018 03:00 - flight from TFS to BCN arriving at 07:15, next 21.07.2018 11:20 - flight from BCN to OLB, arriving at 12:45.

I received an email from Vueling stating the following:

1. Origin airport changed from Tenerife South to Tenerife North (about 70 km).
2. Date and time of leg 1 changed to 20.07.2018 20:25 - 21.07.2018 00:40.

So now I'm going to have almost 11-hour layover instead of 4 hours, besides difficulties getting to another airport.

Am I entitled to any compensation regarding the change of airports, and am I entitled to have a free hotel / transfer in Barcelona from Vueling, or all my options are either to accept the alternative route or get a full refund?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar cases. A few options from my experience. You should call (or write) support:

- **Explain the situation and ask to change tickets for other airline or time** (you should look at the schedule to tell the agent what you want. I have done this with Air France -> KLM and with Air France -> Lufthansa)
- **Ask for the full refund** (they have to return the full ticket price as long as anything you paid for seat or luggage. I have done such with nonrefundable tickets of KLM because they refused to change the tickets but there were cheaper options from other carriers)